# A DocumentException

Tags: hibernate

I'm a beginner of hibernate4 The error happend when I use myeclipse to create a projection with hibernate4 . finished configuration and during insert data to mysql. it's show me an erroe like this:

```
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: http://www.jboss.org/dtd/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd%20 Nested exception: http://www.jboss.org/dtd/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd%20
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:78)
... 13 more
```

but when i use hibernate 3 there is no error . I don't know why so 
I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://www.jboss.org/dtd/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd%20
```

It seems there is some whitespace at the end, please remove it.

```
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" <-- no whitespace at end.
```